# Show that a sequence is convergent - Strategy to divide through by dominant term

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

We need to show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{(2n+1)(n+2)}{3n^2 + 3n}$ for $n=1, 2, ...$ is convergent and find its limit.

Now in my book they suggest:

> Rearrange the expressions for $a_n$ by dividing both numerator and denominator by the dominant term $n^2$, which gives the following result:

> $$a_n = \frac{(2n+1)(n+2)}{3n^2 + 3n} = \frac{(2+1/n)(1+2/n)}{3+3/n}$$

- I understand that if we divide $3n^2 + 3n$ by $n^2$ we will get $3+3/n$ in the denominator.
- But I can't follow how they get to this numerator. I tried $\frac{(2n+1)(n+2)}{n^2} = \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{5}{n} + 2$ but that doesn't resemble the numerator they have in this example. Am I overlooking something? I would like to have some help to understand the example given and what algebraic manipulation leads to this result.

Comment: Divide a factor of $n$ into each piece separately

Comment: Divide each bracket by n rather than the whole lot by $n^2$.

Comment: Your $2/n^2 + 5/n + 2$ is also right and leads to the same result (that the numerator tends to $2$ as $n \to \infty$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2n+1)(n+2)\frac {1}{n^2}= \left(\frac{2n+1}{n} \right) \left( \frac{n+2}{n} \right) = (2+ \frac 1n)(1+\frac 2n)$$